# Why does zinc sulfide glow when hit by electrons?

Tags: atoms, elements, atomic-structure, phosphorescence

In cathode ray tube experiment in order to check the direction of flow of electrons a hole was made in a note and behind it phosphorescent material zinc sulfide it was coated.

Why does zinc sulfide glow when hit by electrons?
What causes this glow?

Comment: Related: [Why does zinc sulfide glow?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34244/why-does-zinc-sulfide-glow); [Why did scientists use a zinc-sulfide coated screen to detect the alpha, beta, and gamma radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190123/why-did-scientists-use-a-zinc-sulfide-coated-screen-to-detect-the-alpha-beta-a); [If cathode rays travel from the cathode to the anode how do they make zinc sulphide glow?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257579/if-cathode-rays-travel-from-the-cathode-to-the-anode-how-do-they-make-zinc-sulph)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of phosphorescence. The Wikipedia page of zinc sulfide and phosphorescence can explain it better than I do, but in short, when zinc sulfide get hit by electrons, electrons transfer some of its energy to zinc sulfide and excites its electron. Zinc sulfide stores the energy for a while, then emit light when the electron goes back to its ground level.

Comment: And it is cheaper than diamond ( that also glows).